# Delete everything before "/" on every line

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I am trying to delete certain text that appears before `/` on every line.

I have something like:

```
testing.db.com/7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123
testing.db.com/8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6
```

and I just want to end up with:

```
7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123
8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6
```

Can anyone help me with a regular expression? Everything I have found is deleting *after* `/`, not *before*.

Comment: pipe it through something like:  sed -e 's|[^/]*/||'

Comment: `awk -F/ '{print $2}' file > newfile`

Comment: @Theophrastus that's the most solid solution proposed so far. Turn it into an answer and I for one will upvote it.

Comment: @Theophrastus your regEx looks good but its doing the opposite its stripping everthing and just leaving  com/

Comment: @user3738022 not when i do it: echo "testing.db.com/8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6" | sed -e 's|[^/]*/||'   ends up returning this:
8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6

Comment: Really :( I wish i could share a screenshot its just doing the opposite for me. does adding the echo have an impact? on the output because I just added the regex sed -e 's|[^/]*/||'

Comment: @user3738022  i'm afraid we're into the land of idiosyncratic behavior now, because it's not anything specific to "echo".  (i get the same 'as described' result if i put those two lines in a file and '<' to sed)

Comment: Its fine, thank you for your help I have managed to piece together one thats stripping all characters up to "/" [^/]*$

Answer (score 5):

Using `cut` :

```
$ cut -sd'/' -f2 file.txt   ##This will print only the lines containing /
7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123
8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6
```

The following suggestions assumes that `/` appears only once in a line :

Using `grep` :

```
$ grep -o '[^/]*$' file.txt  ##This will print the lines not having / too
7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123
8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6
```

If you have `/` in all of the lines, you can use these too:

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```bsh
$ while read line; do echo "${line#*/}"; done <file.txt 
7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123
8a8589bf-49e3-4cd7-af15-6753067355c6
```

Or `python` :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
```

**Note that as far as your example is concerned all of the above suggestions are valid.**

Comment: I'm upvoting this for `cut` - because good work and that's what I came here to say. But you've got it in mixed company - for this task these commands are nowhere near equivalent. `cut` should be the only thing here - to make it act like `grep -o` use `cut -sd`. Those other two commands are merely a distraction. Run some time tests on large inputs and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @mikeserv Thank you very much as always..i was taking the OP's examples literally..anyway i am clarifying it now..

Comment: Let's hope that / doesn't appear more than once per line. Try `cut -d/ -f2-` and ignore the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

easy enough with sed:

```
echo "testing.db.com/7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123" | sed -e "s/.*\///"
```

basic syntax is "s/search/replace/" and here we search for `.*\/` which means everything ending with slash (escaped) and we replace it with nothing.

Comment: Let's hope that `/` doesn't appear more than once per line

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
< file.txt perl -pe 's/.*\///'
```

Comment: Let's hope that / doesn't appear more than once per line. You might want to use `'s|.*?/||'` to bullet-proof the suggestion.

Comment: @roaima We don't have enough elements to judge; according to the example either matching greedily or lazily it's the same, because there's always one single `/`; if there are more than one in the part to exclude than one should match greedily like I did, otherwise one should match lazily like you suggested. Not knowing this, since the string looks pretty regular (only composed by numbers and `-`), I'd prefer to bullet-proof the solution against possible subdirs in the link (e.g. `testing.db.com/subdir`)

Comment: good argument; I'm convinced!

Answer (score -1):

Two methods using sed:

```
sed -i "s|testing.db.com/||g" file_path_here
```

or

```
echo "testing.db.com/7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123" | sed -e "s|testing.db.com/||g"
```

Comment: I have tried this too but it is doing the opposite :( It's leaving com/ instead of the other way round

Comment: I don't understand. I tested it on my server and it works fine, it leaves "7fad416d-f2b3-4259-b98d-2449957a3123" only.

Comment: I dont know why it didnt work for me but i ended up using this one [^/]*$