# How do delete everything before an specific symbol?

Tags: sed, delete

I need to remove all numbers before "|" symbol. I tried some suggestions on a previous question ([Delete everything before "/" on every line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213371/delete-everything-before-on-every-line)) but did not work for me.
For example:

```
113|gm1.1_g
115|gm1.3_g
350400|fgenesh1_kg.28251_#_1_#_remain_c2214
```

Then I would like to have:

```
gm1.1_g
gm1.3_g
fgenesh1_kg.28251_#_1_#_remain_c2214
```

Thanks

Comment: From the linked question, which methods did you try and in what way, precisely, did they not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex that mean "all numbers before |" (at the line start) is:

```
^[0-9]*|
```

Use that with sed:

```
$ echo "113|gm1.1_g" | sed 's/^[0-9]*|//'
gm1.1_g
```

Awk:

```
$ echo "113|gm1.1_g" | awk 'sub(/^[0-9]*\|/,"")'
gm1.1_g
```

shell:

```
$ a="113|gm1.1_g"; r='^[0-9]*\|(.*)$'; [[ $a =~ $r ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```