# Command which removes data left side of ";" (semicolon) on each row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

Need here command which removes any data at left side of `;` (semicolon) on each following row:

```
07:48;1563101282.M178569P409830.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
08:00;1563102004.M49870P436474.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
08:16;1563102961.M195946P457876.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
08:32;1563103921.M334168P463856.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
08:48;1563104883.M883187P502037.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
09:00;1563105603.M799240P519637.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
09:16;1563106561.M419884P547969.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
09:32;1563107524.M145768P582635.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
09:48;1563108483.M632493P607265.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
10:00;1563109203.M675460P633790.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
10:16;1563110163.M299406P663234.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
10:32;1563111121.M682713P685072.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
```

In some way that it would results in rows as follows:

```
1563101282.M178569P409830.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102004.M49870P436474.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102961.M195946P457876.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563103921.M334168P463856.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563104883.M883187P502037.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563105603.M799240P519637.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563106561.M419884P547969.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563107524.M145768P582635.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563108483.M632493P607265.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563109203.M675460P633790.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563110163.M299406P663234.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563111121.M682713P685072.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
```

Would it be please in GNU `awk`, `egrep` or `sed`?

Comment: Would it be prefered in `shell script` or in `bash`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete everything before "/" on every line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213371/delete-everything-before-on-every-line)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another `sed` variant:

```
sed 's/^[^;]*;//' file
```

Replace any non-semicolon characters (`[^;]*`) at the beginning of the line (the first `^`) followed by a semicolon with an empty string.

Answer (score 34):

This is what the `cut` command is for.

```
cut -d';' -f2-
```

Comment: Since there are only two columns, you could omit trailing `-`.

Comment: Good point Cyrus made - although for OP I would suggest it is left in for some scalability, ie if they add more data delimited by semicolons, they don't need to modify the script.

Comment: +1. While the accepted answer works, I feel that in general this answer is less complicated to understand and should have been the accepted answer instead.  I also agree on @QuickishFM that the trailing `-` helps for accidental second semicolons per line or if the worked-on data expands on more than just two fields to still get the remainder of the line.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation would be nice. +1 though. This is the simple answer.

Answer (score 9):

In `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { print $2 }'
```

or, even simpler

```
awk -F";" '{print $2}'
```

(thank you, [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu), for this simplified version)

Comment: `awk -F";" '{print $2}'` is the same but shorter

Comment: thank you. I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^.*;(.*)/\1/' file
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?!.*;).*' file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
< inputfile egrep ';' | cut -f 2 -d ';'
```

-This command and you will get this!

Comment: I recommend testing it.

Comment: @Cyrus, if you were referring to the minor issue with that misplaced filename, you might as well have mentioned it straight up, or edited to fix it...

Answer (score 5):

There are, as the existing answers already show, many ways to do this. Here's another GNU `grep` approach:

```
$ grep -oP ';\K.*' file
1563101282.M178569P409830.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102004.M49870P436474.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102961.M195946P457876.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563103921.M334168P463856.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563104883.M883187P502037.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563105603.M799240P519637.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563106561.M419884P547969.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563107524.M145768P582635.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563108483.M632493P607265.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563109203.M675460P633790.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563110163.M299406P663234.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563111121.M682713P685072.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
```

The `-o` makes grep print only the matching portion of the line and the `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. PCRE has `\K` which means "ignore anything matched before". Putting all that together, the command will find the first `;`, discard it and then print the rest of the line.

Another option is to use perl in its awk-mode (`-a`):

```
$ perl -F';' -lane 'print $F[1]' file
1563101282.M178569P409830.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102004.M49870P436474.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102961.M195946P457876.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563103921.M334168P463856.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563104883.M883187P502037.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563105603.M799240P519637.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563106561.M419884P547969.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563107524.M145768P582635.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563108483.M632493P607265.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563109203.M675460P633790.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563110163.M299406P663234.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563111121.M682713P685072.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
```

Or use perl like sed and delete everything up to the first `;`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?;//' file
1563101282.M178569P409830.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102004.M49870P436474.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102961.M195946P457876.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563103921.M334168P463856.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563104883.M883187P502037.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563105603.M799240P519637.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563106561.M419884P547969.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563107524.M145768P582635.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563108483.M632493P607265.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563109203.M675460P633790.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563110163.M299406P663234.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563111121.M682713P685072.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
```

Comment: "awl-mode-perl" to emulate `cut -d\; -f2-` is `'$, = ";"; print @F[1..$#F]'`

Answer (score 4):

Considering that this input is `Data01.txt`, it may be done as:

`awk -F";" '{ print $2 }' Data01.txt > Data01\ Ready.txt`

Which will output `Data01 Ready.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

Python for fun, now.

```
python -c "import sys; [print(line.strip().split(';')[1]) for line in sys.stdin]" < input_file.txt

1563101282.M178569P409830.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102004.M49870P436474.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563102961.M195946P457876.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563103921.M334168P463856.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563104883.M883187P502037.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563105603.M799240P519637.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563106561.M419884P547969.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563107524.M145768P582635.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563108483.M632493P607265.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563109203.M675460P633790.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563110163.M299406P663234.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
1563111121.M682713P685072.de122.abteilung.com,S=1258,W=1287:2,
```

Because `print` adds a newline, you either have to remove it with `end=''` or strip out the newline from the file with `.strip()`.  Both work fine; I chose the latter here.